# App reject issue due to third party signin like apple,facebook etc

Tags: swift, facebook, google-signin

The App got rejected in the app store due to the following issues while signing in with apple or facebook or google.

1) The app shows not connected to internet whereas code is already in place to check for internet as given below:

```
let status = Reach().connectionStatus()
                                     switch status {
                                     case .unknown, .offline:
                                         print("Not connected")
                                       self.navigationController?.view.makeToast("Please connect the internet", duration: 3.0, position: .bottom)
                                     case .online(.wwan):
                                         print("Connected via WWAN")
                                     case .online(.wiFi):
                                         print("Connected via WiFi")

                                     }
```

2) Also,the google or facebook sign in is showing white screen.

[image]

Comment: Get tested on device before you deploy on appStore. Try to debug your code, to find-out loop-holes in your app.

Comment: Have tested on device also.I never had this white screen issue while signing in using facebook or google.

Comment: Ok...you are facing this issue after deployment. Have you added any crash reporting solution like crashlytics in your app. So you will able to tackle issue in app after deployment.

Comment: Yes after submitted to app store.No i have not added any crashlytics in the app.

Comment: Can you try testing after a complete hard reset of your device(iPhone, iPad), followed by a fresh installation of the app, and check if you are able to repro this issue

Comment: okay i will check